# Android audio Manager trouble

Tags: android

I am using Android audio Manager and in my app when you click a button it silents the phone and at certain time it brings the phone back to normal mode. but the problem is that when i click the button it changes it to silent but then automaticly it changes it back to normal mode again for some reason. i am using

in one file im using

```
soAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
              soAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

and in another file i am using

```
goAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
              goAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Comment: Those snippets are functionally identical.

Comment: Also, you should prevent an Error-Message from the LogCat or more Source Code so we can help you...

Answer (score 0):

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```